# Taking photo android

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, onactivityresult

I'm having some problem in my android application when I try to take a picture and get it from onActivityResult(). I wanted to be sure that the code will work so I have just copied the exact code of this page http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html.

So these are the methods I used; I call dispatchTakePictureIntent() when the user click on a button.`

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 15);
        }
    }
}`
```

The problem is that when the onActivityResult() method is called, I get the right requestCode, the right resultCode but the third parameter is null. I want to get the image Bitmap or Path, but I can't without it. Why does this happen? Is it because this code isn't supposed to return that parameter? In that case, how should I modify it?

Comment: your path is already here :  `mCurrentPhotoPath`

Comment: Yes I tried to use that path before but it didn't worked, it was because it is defined as "file:" + image.getAbsolutePaht(); I removed "file:" and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this code tested.

Take picture

```
private void TakePicture(){
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

Save to file

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case 0:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            try{  

                String filename = "name.jpg";
                File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dest = new File(sd, filename);
                Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                bp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                //

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
                Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the code I was using before, but then I found out that on some devices causes crash. Anyway I solved my problem, I get the path from the variable I already have, without adding "file:" as the example does.

Answer (score 0):

The thumbnail image in `onActivityResult()` is received only if you do not specify a file URI for saving the image after taking a picture. Remove this line from your code if you want to receive the preview image:

`takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
 Uri.fromFile(photoFile));`